# Maven Reimport IntelliJ not working cannot transfer artifact to central repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

i changed the maven settings.xml to point to a local repository and now when i try to remove the local repository tag to point to the default .m2/repository folder and run reimport on intellij, or when i run reimport on the project with local repository, i get this error:

Could not transfer artifact org.kie:kie-ci:pom:7.41.0.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to 127.0.0.1:8866 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

This error persists all across all my projects when i run reimport.

This is my pom.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-ci -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>7.41.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is my settings. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!--<localRepository>/Users/Eugene/drools/droolsEngine/dependencies</localRepository>-->
</settings>
```

Please help. thanks

Comment: What is your OS? Do you have antivirus/firewall? Please try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan. Also show your `hosts` file content.

Comment: Try if it helps to restart the PC or IDE.

Comment: Hi all, found the issue was with fiddler messing with my network settings. Disabled fiddler and the wifi settings were reconfigured so now it works

Answer (score 0):

Check if proxy was not not configured on your PC accidentally. In my case proxy was configured by https://www.telerik.com/fiddler on port 8866. And I overlooked this fact.